# XAMPP response too long

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have `php` file and I tried to run it using localhost, and `localhost` was running normally. Then, I shut down my laptop and when I tried to run my php file again, localhost takes long time and actually, I didn't edit anything in my php file. I use windows 7.

I have tried to edit my

`httpd.conf.

I change

`ServerName Localhost` to `ServerName 127.0.0.1:80`.

I also have edited

`my.ini`.

I uncommented

`bind-address="127.0.0.1"`

I also edited

`config.inc.php`

I change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost' to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

But, the response still takes long time. The loading time takes too much time. What may I do to solve that problem? Anybody knows? It would help me a lot. Thank you

Comment: open up developer tools in chrome, click on network tab, and mouse over the request that you are making. Where is most of your time spent? Initial connection, TTFB or content download?